# SharePoint 2010 Show User Name and Sign Out

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How do we edit the master page to Show the User name with the drop down showing just (Sign out, Sign as a different user). Yet remove everything else (site actions, browse, page, my site, my profile, my settings)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can edit the Welcome.aspx at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES` change **14** to your Sharepoint Version.

[image]

Then add a **`Visible="False"`** (take note this is case sensitive) property to the   like such
[image]

However, if you want to add items to it, [here](http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/how-to-edit-the-welcome-drop-down-menu-in-sharepoint-2010/) is a guide.